# Can't find file executable in your configured search path for INTEL C++ compiler (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, codeblocks

I want to debug my c++ code using code::blocks. I open a new project and paste my code. But there is above error. To be honest, I'm not sure what is my compiler! when I want to run my code, I write:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 mycodename.cpp
```

in the terminal. 
How can I remove above error in Linux? 
A step by step answer is highly appreciated. 
I change the compiler from `setting...compiler` to gnu gcc but the error is about intel compiler!

Comment: The title says Intel compiler, the body says GCC. Which is it?

Comment: I add intel compiler to the code block because I didn't know what to choose as my compiler in code::blocks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: If you didn't install the Intel compiler then you don't have it.

Comment: I can not find gcc c++ in compiler lists of code::block @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: There are a lot o gcc choices, do you know which one should I choose?@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Nope. Never used Code::Blocks before.

Comment: Should I choose gnu gcc compiler? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @Monaphys Usually this (GCC) is the standard compiler installed on linux systems.

Comment: Do you know how can I change compiler in code::blocks?@user0042

Comment: Read the documentation of Code::Blocks if you need to configure it. But before that, learn to use `g++` and `gdb` in the command line (because Code::Blocks is running them).

Comment: You cannot learn programming without reading and experimenting a lot. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html for an important insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to debug my c++ code using code::blocks.

**Don't, because you can't.**

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is just an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), that is it is some source code editor capable to run compilers and debuggers. So Code::Blocks is *not* a compiler and is *not* a debugger (but it could run them).

I won't explain how you might use Code::Blocks. It has some documentation and some forum. I will rather try to explain how you should debug your C++ code.

#### compilation with `g++`

First, you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (it a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), more precisely the  *GNU Compiler Collection*; you'll use it with `g++` program to compile C++ code, with `gcc` to compile C code, etc....). **Read the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).**

To compile a simple C++ program made of a *single* C++ [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit) (a C++ file `yoursourcecode.cpp` including some headers) into an executable `yourprog` use:

```
 g++  -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -g yoursourcecode.cpp -o yourprog
```

Notice that:

- order of program arguments to `g++` are important.
- `-std=gnu++11` defines your C++ dialect
- `-Wall -Wextra` asks for all warnings and some extra of them. You really want warnings. You then need to improve your source code to get no warnings at all and repeat the compilation.
- `-g` ask for debug info (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format). You want to be able to debug.
- `-o yourprog` asks the compiler to generate as output the `yourprog` [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable

BTW, you cannot use Code::Blocks to compile your code. You could configure it to run the above command to compile it.

If your program is made of *several* C++ source files (and several translation unit) you need to compile every translation unit into an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code), and then to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) these to make your executable. So with two source files `yourfirstsource.cpp` and `yoursecondsource.cpp` you need to run:

- `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c yourfirstsource.cpp -o yourfirstsource.o` to compile the first `yourfirstsource.cpp` into the `yourfirstsource.o` object file.
- `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c yoursecondsource.cpp -o yoursecondsource.o` to compile the second translation unit.
- `g++ yourfirstsource.o  yoursecondsource.o -o yourprog` to link both object files into an executable. You might link libraries with `-L`*dir* and `-l`*libname* arguments (order is important, from higher level to lowel level libraries)

In practice, if you have several C++ files, you'll better use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, like  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). That tool will run compilations and link commands like above. *You should be able to compile (and link) on the command line*.

### debugging with `gdb`

Once you have an executable with debug info, you can use the `gdb` debugger. **Read the [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) documentation**. I *strongly recommend using `gdb` in a terminal*. Start it with `gdb ./yourprog` (or `gdb -tui ./yourprog` if you want a terminal interface), then you get a `(gdb)` prompt and you can type debugger commands. The most useful ones are `run` (or `r`), `break` (or `b`), `list` (or `l`), `print` (or `p`), `backtrace` (or `bt`).

If you want to run your program directly, type its file path, e.g. `./yourprog` in a command (i.e. some terminal). Be aware of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

For benchmarking purposes, it is better to ask your `g++` compiler to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) with `-O1` or `-O2` etc.

### but what about Code::Blocks

That tool is an editor, also able to run the `g++` compilation and `gdb` debugging commands above. But you really need to become familar with these `g++` and `gdb` tools on the command line. Once you can do that, **dive into the [Code::Blocks documentation](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html)** to understand how to configure your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (BTW my preference is `emacs`).

Code::Blocks is not able to compile your code or debug your program. It is just running external programs (such as the `g++` compiler or the `gdb` debugger), but you should first learn to use `g++` and `gdb`  by yourself (outside of Code::Blocks or any other source code editor).

---

BTW, Intel makes a [proprietary C++ compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/) (I heard it is called `icc`, and you might need to pay for it). And there is also [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/), which is (open source or) free software (like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is, but with a different license). Its `clang++` program accepts arguments similar to those for `g++`. In many cases you could simply replace `g++` by `clang++` to use that Clang compiler.

Be also aware of the [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). You'll need to configure your shell (perhaps your `~/.bashrc`) to change it.

I strongly recommend to learn how to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system tool, like [git](http://git-scm.com/) (which has good videos and documentation and is very powerful).

Comment: You'll use `gdb`. Later you might (or not) configure Code::Blocks or some better source code editor to run `gdb`

Comment: If my program is made of one source code, I don't need to use gdb and code block, Am I correct? As I understood from your answer, if there is any warning, the command g++  -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -g yoursourcecode.cpp -o yourprog will show them, yes?

Comment: You need `gdb` for debugging. It is irrelevant at compile time (except that you need to pass `-g` to `g++` to be later able to use `gdb`). BTW please *try* the commands I explained you.

Comment: Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".

Comment: For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./yourprog...done.
(gdb)

Comment: above comments are output of typing "gdb -tui ./yourprog". Is the output ok? What should I do then?!

Comment: @MonaPhys: don't comment your question, but perhaps edit it or better yet ask another one with some [MCVE]. And of course you need to **read the documentation** (and I gave links in my answer that you should follow).

Comment: "For benchmarking purposes, it is better to ask g++ to optimize with -O1 or -O2 etc." what does it mean  and how can I do that?

Comment: Please **take *several days* to read the documentation** I pointed in my answer. SO won't teach you what you can find in the documentation.