# riscv/gcc/ld - "Undefined reference to printf" using own script to link

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld, riscv

Currently, I'm learning RISC-V, use the RISC-V toolchain, and edit a new ld script for my embedded. I write a example, and compile to watch the opcode.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h> //float.c

int main()
{
float a=1.04;
printf("a=%f\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

**My steps is:**

```
1. riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -S float.c　　*//generate assembly code*

2. riscv64-unknown-elf-as float.s -o float.o　　*//generate obj file*

3. riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -T elf64lriscv1.x float.o *//use own script to link, -T is using other script*
```

and then,it will show *"float.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `printf'*

**I'm try**

Add `-lc` parameter, but doesn't working, it will show more undefined message.

**My ld script**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-littleriscv", "elf64-littleriscv","elf64-littleriscv")
OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("/path/to/install/riscv/toolchain/riscv64-unknow-elf/lib");
/*MEMORY{  //for my embedded allocation
  flash : org = 0x0, l = 0x10000
  ram : org= 0x10000, l = 512
}*/
SECTIONS{
_start =0x10000;
.text :
{
  *(.text)
}
.bss :
{
  *(.bss)
  *(.sbss)
}}
```

Also, i'm trying to use the default script, like this command:

```
$ riscv-unknown-elf-ld float.o -o float
```

but it is same result....
please help me!

Regards!

Comment: You need to learn not only RISC-V but much much more. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: BTW, why don't you use Linux on your RISCV-V ? It might be easier, even if Linux is not completely mature on that platform...

Comment: I got a RISCV VM on linux, and i relocated to my MCU(TI 320F28335) using CCS, now i'm trying to compile C code(the toolchain is on linux) and get the RISCV instruction load to MCU and execute

Comment: My guess is that you are lacking a lot of skills and knowledge. You might need months or years of efforts to get them. What you want to achieve is much more difficult and complex than what you imagine (because you need to learn a lot). And I was suggesting running Linux on your RISCV hardware (even if it is some virtual one).

Comment: Yes.... I'm learning a lot new knowledge everyday... that is difficult for me

Comment: No, RISC-V is quite easy (easier than x86-64). But **programming is difficult**. What you need to learn is *not* RISC-V specific. And you need to learn a lot. So be patient. Did you consider following some formal programming class, and some CS education ?

Comment: For example, reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) would be useful to you (in addition of the links given in my answer) and they are unrelated to RISC-V. It seems that you are missing some basics.

Comment: And floating point is difficult; read http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more. Why do you need an example with `float`  ?

Comment: The hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082345/841108) also apply to you...

Comment: hi Starynkevitch, thank you for your answer, the float just a example, my problem is about "printf" cannot link, i will do my best to learning more knowledge!

Comment: Be aware (and tell your manager, if you are employed) that you'll need *months* of work, and perhaps more. Your lack of knowledge is mostly unrelated to RISC V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is provided by the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (and is very difficult to implement). You need to link it (perhaps by adding `-lc` to your `riscv-unknown-elf-ld` command, or by giving the complete path of that library)

You might pass [additional options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/ld/Options.html#Options) to your `riscv-unknown-elf-ld` perhaps `-M`, `-L` *search-dir*,  `--trace`, `--verbose`, etc. Read also more carefully the chapter about [`ld` scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts).

Since you are cross-compiling, you might need to cross-compile some `libc` from  source code.

You need to spend more time understanding the behavior of [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) and [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object files and executable format (see also [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)). Consider reading [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/)

You could use other cross- [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/binutils/index.html) programs (like cross- `objdump`, `nm`, `readelf` etc...) to explore the relevant object files.

If you are coding for a bare metal system, you might want to compile in freestanding mode ([passing `-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) to your GCC) and provide so implement your own `printf` (or other output) function. Existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C libraries could inspire you (but you need to find one or work many months to develop some equivalent). Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org).

I recommend also reading about OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) (since the OS concepts are relevant to you, because an embedded system on the bare metal share features with OSes). [OSDEV wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) might also be helpful (but is not about RISC-V).

You could need *several months* of work (or even years), so budget it appropriately.

BTW, I am surprized that you use a `float` in your example. Floating point is difficult. See [`floating-point-gui.de`](http://floating-point-gui.de/) ; For a first try, I would consider using integer only.

Comment: Which means that you are progressing

Comment: my script have the SEARCH_DIR path, the -L parameter can work? or i use default and adding -L?

Comment: I don't know `binutils` well enough. I provided more links. You'll spend several days at least solving your issue. And we can't help more, because you don't give enough details in your question